# About proving that the interior of the boundary of a closed set is empty

Tags: general-topology

Using the notation of Int, Cl and $\partial$ for interior, closure and boundary respectively, I'm trying to prove that Int$(\partial A) = \emptyset $, with A a closed set. However, the material that I find on the internet in this regard uses as a definition of boundary "*The set of points $x \in X$ such that every neighborhood of $x$ contains at least one point of $S$ and at least one point not of $S$*", while I'm using $\partial S = \text{Cl}(S) - \text{Int}(S)$.

I would like some hint on how to start the proof from the point of view of the definition shown above. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite easy to see that your definition of $\partial S = \text{Cl}(S) - \text{Int}(S)$ is equivalent to the one you saw: every neighbourhood of $x$ intersecting $S$ says $x \in \text{Cl}(S)$ and every neighbourhood of $x$ containing a point not in $S$ is the same as saying $x \notin \text{Int}(S)$.

Also consider $\partial A$ for $A$ closed, we write it as $ \text{Cl}(A) - \text{Int}(A) = A - \text{Int}(A)$, as $A$ is closed. So we subtracted from $A$ the *maximal* open subset of $A$ which means there cannot be any  non-empty open subsets inside $A - \text{Int}(A) (\subseteq A)$, because that would contradict the maximality of $\text{Int}(A)$. Hence $\partial A$ has empty interior.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if this is what you are asking for.

$x \in ~\text{interior of} ~S$ denotes that there is a neighborhood around $x$ that is completely contained in $S$.  This implies, per the definition that you have stated for the boundary of $S$, that $x \in ~\text{interior of} ~S$ implies that it is not the case that $x \in ~\text{the boundary of} ~S$.